# String slice to string?

Tags: go

I'm writing a program that takes normal flags and a single "non-flag" argument, like this:

```
my-prog -level 1 map.txt
```

To process `map.txt` I use `flag.Args()[:1]`, but if you pass that to functions that takes a string, this compiler error appears:

```
cannot use flag.Args()[:1] (type []string) as type string in assignment
```

How can I convert `flag.Args()[:1]` to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the first `string` instead of slicing it: `flag.Args()[0]`

Or you can use the `flag.Arg(0)` function to get the first argument only.